# Patterns in React (wrapper)

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, react-hoc

Good day. I'm building a tree of components and want to use functions of root component in other components of tree. I throw function reference through all tree.
Also I use the object if me need get value from the function in not root componet.
Can you help me?
Can you show me how to do this as HOC ?
If it will be not so hard for you show examples on my code.

```
import React from 'react';

class Page extends React.Component{

    Answer = {
        value : ''
    }

    doSomething(){

        console.log(this.Answer.value);
        console.log('Ready!');
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Body 
                        ParentFunc={()=>this.doSomething()} 
                        ParentParameters={this.Answer}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Page

class Body extends React.Component{
    render(){

        const{
            ParentFunc,
            ParentParameters
        } = this.props
        
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <SomeComponent 
                        ParentFunc={()=>ParentFunc()}
                        ParentParameters={ParentParameters}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class SomeComponent extends React.Component{

    getAnswer(){
        
        const{
            ParentFunc,
            ParentParameters
        } = this.props

        ParentParameters.value = 'Some text'
        
        ParentFunc()
    }
    
    render(){
        
        return(
            <div onClick={()=>this.getAnswer()}>
                We can?
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to make a Higher Order Component of or from? "want to use functions of root component in other components of tree" sounds more like you want to create a Context provider and provide the functions to call via a Context.

Comment: Attention!
Don't use context to avoid passing properties down multiple levels. The real need arises in cases where the same data must be available in many components at different levels.

Comment: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html
I want to use pattern

Comment: So what are you wanting to compose that you aren't already composing? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I don't want to throw function through all components if I want to use this func in another component

Comment: Higher Order Components don't solve for the issue of props drilling, using a React Context helps with this issue. The header text from [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) reads as follows: "Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level." This, as you describe, seems to be the exact issue you are trying to eliminate. If you like I can provide an answer with a possible solution using a Context provider.

Comment: but in manual of React written that it is bad idea use context as you say!
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: I see, if you are referring to [the before you use context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context) section, this is just saying that you can enclose the `<div onClick={()=>this.getAnswer()}>...<` in a prop and pass this down to `Body` and `SomeComponent` instead.

Comment: thank for help look like that by context right now we can drill props 
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe a Higher Order Component alone will solve your basic issue of prop drilling. A [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) would be a better fit for providing values and functions generally to "want to use functions of root component in other components of tree".

> #### Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.
>
> In a typical React application, data is passed top-down (parent to
> child) via props, but such usage can be cumbersome for certain types
> of props (e.g. locale preference, UI theme) that are required by many
> components within an application. Context provides a way to share
> values like these between components without having to explicitly pass
> a prop through every level of the tree.

Start by creating your Context and Provider component:

```
const QnAContext = React.createContext({
  answer: {
    value: ""
  },
  doSomething: () => {}
});

const QnAProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const answer = {
    value: ""
  };

  const doSomething = () => {
    console.log(answer.value);
    console.log("Ready!");
  };

  return (
    <QnAContext.Provider value={{ answer, doSomething }}>
      {children}
    </QnAContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Render `QnAProvider` in your app somewhere wrapping the React subtree you want to have access to the values being provided:

```
<QnAProvider>
  <Page />
</QnAProvider>
```

Consuming the Context:

- Class-based components consume contexts via the [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern.

  ```
   <QnAContext.Consumer>
     {({ answer, doSomething }) => (
       <SomeComponent doSomething={doSomething} answer={answer}>
         We can?
       </SomeComponent>
     )}
   </QnAContext.Consumer>
  ```
- Functional components can use the [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) React hook

  ```
   const SomeComponent = ({ children }) => {
     const { answer, doSomething } = useContext(QnAContext);

     getAnswer = () => {
       answer.value = "Some text";

       doSomething();
     };

     return <div onClick={this.getAnswer}>{children}</div>;
   };
  ```

Here is where using a Higher Order Component may become useful. You can abstract the `QnAContext.Consumer` render props pattern into a HOC:

```
const withQnAContext = (Component) => (props) => (
  <QnAContext.Consumer>
    {(value) => <Component {...props} {...value} />}
  </QnAContext.Consumer>
);
```

Then you can decorate components you want to have the context values injected into.

```
const DecoratedSomeComponent = withQnAContext(SomeComponent);

...

<DecoratedSomeComponent>We can with HOC?</DecoratedSomeComponent>
```

**Note:** The point of doing all this was to move the values and functions that were previously defined in `Page` into the Context, so they are no longer passed from `Page` though `Body` to `SomeComponent` (or *any* other children components).

## Demo

[image: Edit patterns-in-react-wrapper]

Sandbox Code:

```
const QnAContext = React.createContext({
  answer: {
    value: ""
  },
  doSomething: () => {}
});

const QnAProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const answer = {
    value: ""
  };

  const doSomething = () => {
    console.log(answer.value);
    console.log("Ready!");
  };

  return (
    <QnAContext.Provider value={{ answer, doSomething }}>
      {children}
    </QnAContext.Provider>
  );
};

const withQnAContext = (Component) => (props) => (
  <QnAContext.Consumer>
    {(value) => <Component {...props} {...value} />}
  </QnAContext.Consumer>
);

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  getAnswer = () => {
    const { doSomething, answer } = this.props;

    answer.value = "Some text";

    doSomething();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={this.getAnswer}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

const DecoratedSomeComponent = withQnAContext(SomeComponent);

class Body extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <QnAContext.Consumer>
            {({ answer, doSomething }) => (
              <SomeComponent doSomething={doSomething} answer={answer}>
                We can?
              </SomeComponent>
            )}
          </QnAContext.Consumer>
        </div>
        <div>
          <DecoratedSomeComponent>We can with HOC?</DecoratedSomeComponent>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Page extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Body />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <QnAProvider>
        <Page />
      </QnAProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current code I am making the assumption that `Body` does not modify the values of `ParentFunc` and `ParentParameters` before passing them down to `SomeComponent`.

You have a hierarchy

```
<Page>
  <Body>
    <SomeComponent>
  </Body>
</Page>
```

and you want to pass props from `Page` to `SomeComponent` without going through `Body`.

#### You can do this using `children`

`children` is [a special prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) representing the JSX child elements of the component.  We make it so that `Body` renders the  `children` that it got through props:

```
class Body extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

We set that `children` prop by using a `<SomeComponent/>` element inside of the `<Body>`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Body>
          <SomeComponent
            ParentFunc={() => this.doSomething()}
            ParentParameters={this.Answer}
          />
        </Body>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that you cannot directly modify the value that you got from the parent, which is what you were doing with `ParentParameters.value = 'Some text'`.  If you want to update the state of the parent then you need to do that through your callback function props.  So your code should look something like this:

```
import React from "react";

class Body extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showAnswer: false
  };

  onClick() {
    // update answer in parent
    this.props.setAnswer("Some text");
    // change state to reveal answer
    this.setState({ showAnswer: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.showAnswer && <div>Answer is: {this.props.answer}</div>}
        <div onClick={() => this.onClick()}>We can?</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Page extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ""
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Body>
            <SomeComponent
              answer={this.state.value}
              setAnswer={(answer) => this.setState({ value: answer })}
            />
          </Body>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Page;
```